# Run time error 9 - Subscript out of range when copying from one workbook to other

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open and copy the sheet data from a CSV file and paste it in another workbook but I am getting *run time error 9 - Subscript out of range*.

```
Option Explicit
Sub import()
Dim filename As String

Dim curfilename As String
curfilename = ThisWorkbook.Path

filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Workbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open(filename)
Workbooks(filename).Sheets("Owners").Range("A1:Z10000").Copy    'Error on this line
Workbooks(curfilename).Sheets("Owners").Range("A1:Z10000").Paste

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `.Paste` to `.PasteSpecial`.

Comment: @Jeeped But the error is on the Copy line

Comment: Is there a sheet "Owners"?, When you hover over `filename` what does the tool tip show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Application.GetOpenFilename method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx) returns the full path and file name including extension. You only want the filename with extension if referring to an open workbook; not the path as well.

The [Worksheet.Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx) does not work that way but the [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) does. Change your code to be,

```
Dim Filename As String, currFilename As String
Dim x As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
currFilename = ThisWorkbook.Name
Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
Set x = Workbooks.Open(Filename)

x.Sheets("Owners").Range("A1:Z10000").Copy
Workbooks(currFilename).Sheets("Owners").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
x.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I've corrected a few small errors in variable assignment (`.Path` should have been `.Name`) and added some environment control to avoid silly warning messages.

Alternately, the [Range.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) could be used and you would provide the destination directly as a parameter.

```
x.Sheets("Owners").Range("A1:Z10000").Copy _
  Destination:=Workbooks(curfilename).Sheets("Owners").Range("A1")
```

Note that only the top-left cell in a range is necessary to specify the target of a paste operation.

Comment: by the first method the line "Workbooks(curfilename).Sheets("Owners").Range("A1").PasteSpecial" gives same error again

Comment: Use `curfilename = ThisWorkbook.Name`.

Comment: it worked although due to large amount of data on clipboard it prompts me to save or not save the information on clipboard before pasting do you know how to avoid it

Comment: See my last revision.